# Print filter parameters on a report

Tags: ms-access, parameter

I'm using MS Access 2010.

I have a form with a number of fields of various types (number, text, lookup, checkbox).

Users can right click on any field to filter the form.

Then I have a button that generates a report based on this filtered data:

```
Private Sub Filter_and_Report_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
If Me.FilterOn Then strWhere = Me.Filter
DoCmd.OpenReport "WallsRpt", acViewPreview, , strWhere
End Sub
```

My question is how to list the fields that were filtered in the report (probably in the header/footer).

Answer (score 1):

The Filter condition is in `Me.Filter`: you use it above.

You'd have to parse this, but you must have set it previously to be able to apply it. Ignoring SQL Injection risk (I just got this off the interwebs), you know in this snippet you are filtering on ProductCatID

```
Me.Filter = "ProductCatID = """ & Me.cboShowCat & """"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

You can set a new variable/property (eg `Me.Tag`) for use in the Header/Footer